# stop hover effect when mouse is out if element has class A

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

here is my entire jquery code :

```
$(function(){
    $(".sc").hover(function(){
        $(".sc span.L1").animate({marginRight:'0px'},100);
        $(".sc span.L2").animate({marginRight:'28px'},200);
        $(".sc span.L3").animate({marginRight:'5px'},300);
        $(".sc span.L4").animate({marginRight:'19px'},400);
    }, function(){
        $(".sc span.L1").animate({marginRight:'0px'},100);
        $(".sc span.L2").animate({marginRight:'0px'},200);
        $(".sc span.L3").animate({marginRight:'0px'},300);
        $(".sc span.L4").animate({marginRight:'0px'},400);
    });
    $(".sc").click(function(){
        if ($(".sc div#trigger").hasClass('passive')){
                $(".sc div#trigger").removeClass('passive');
                $(".sc div#trigger").addClass('active');
            }
            else { 
                $(".sc div#trigger").addClass('passive');
                $(".sc div#trigger").removeClass('active');
            };

    });
```

I want to stop hover effect if div#trigger.hasClass('passive').
It means if the class of div#trigger is "passive", I want the hover effect to be disabled, and when the class is "active", to be enabled..

how can I use this code ?!

```
if ($(".sc div#trigger").hasClass('passive')) {
// codes to stop hover effect
}
```

Comment: Be careful to make your html ID's unique. You should not have a `#trigger` element in each `.sc` element.

Comment: thank you, but a question! what problem can ".sc div#trigger " make ?!

Comment: In this case it may not break anything immediately. However your code won't successfully pass an html validator if you have more than one element with `id='trigger'`. Since you tell jQuery to search within `.sc` it will probably work correctly; but the correct and extensible solution would be to change that to `class="trigger"`, and use `.trigger` instead of `#trigger`. (Bear in mind I don't know what your html looks like, so I might be assuming incorrectly -- if you show your html structure I could be more definitive!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector `'.sc div#trigger'` is unnecessarily verbose; since id's are unique, simply use: `'#trigger'`

```
$(function(){
    $('.sc').hover(function(){
        if ( $("#trigger").hasClass('active') ) {
            $(".sc span.L1").animate({marginRight:'0px'},100);
            $(".sc span.L2").animate({marginRight:'28px'},200);
            $(".sc span.L3").animate({marginRight:'5px'},300);
            $(".sc span.L4").animate({marginRight:'19px'},400);
        }
    }, function(){
        if ( $("#trigger").hasClass('active') ) {
            $(".sc span.L1").animate({marginRight:'0px'},100);
            $(".sc span.L2").animate({marginRight:'0px'},200);
            $(".sc span.L3").animate({marginRight:'0px'},300);
            $(".sc span.L4").animate({marginRight:'0px'},400);
        }
    });
    // ...
});
​
```

---

Also, regarding your click event, it is possible to reduce some verbosity here as well; a little known/used function in the jQuery library [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass) can add/remove a class depending on whether it is present or not. This is made even more powerful by the fact that you can trigger this effect on several classes simultaneously by specifying the names in a single string:

```
$(".sc").click( function() {
    $("#trigger").toggleClass('passive active');
});
```

Since an element here can only be in one state at a time, this simply turns off whichever one is currently associated with the element, and turns on the other.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){
    $(".sc .active").hover(function(){
        $(".sc span.L1").animate({marginRight:'0px'},100);
        $(".sc span.L2").animate({marginRight:'28px'},200);
        $(".sc span.L3").animate({marginRight:'5px'},300);
        $(".sc span.L4").animate({marginRight:'19px'},400);
    }, function(){
        $(".sc span.L1").animate({marginRight:'0px'},100);
        $(".sc span.L2").animate({marginRight:'0px'},200);
        $(".sc span.L3").animate({marginRight:'0px'},300);
        $(".sc span.L4").animate({marginRight:'0px'},400);
    });
    $(".sc").click(function(){
        if ($(".sc div#trigger").hasClass('passive')){
                $(".sc div#trigger").removeClass('passive');
                $(".sc div#trigger").addClass('active');
            }
            else { 
                $(".sc div#trigger").addClass('passive');
                $(".sc div#trigger").removeClass('active');
            };

    });
```

Comment: This doesn't work, since the handler will only be bound once - to the element which is currently active, and won't be bound to the others at all. You would need to use a delegated event handler with this approach

Answer (score 0):

May it is what you are looking for:

```
if ($('.sc div#trigger').hasClass('passive')) {
  $('.sc span').stop(true, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

lose the div in div#trigger, you dont need it because an ID uniquely represents an object in DOM tree
if you want to change the class of an element you can do it two ways...your way or just

```
$(".sc #trigger").toggleClass("active");
$(".sc #trigger").toggleClass("pasive");
```

off course, one needs to be initialized from the beginning

now to answer your question, just use `.stop()` - simple as that